# How to user Layout to animation on a Box in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is my image
[image]

This is my box view and I want to animate this box,when use click on "All Items" box then it will create a box Sizes increase(using LayoutTo)

how to do this?

Comment: is this not a dropdown menu?

Comment: you can use RelativeLayout and specify position and size parameters for "dropdown stackLayou"

Comment: You can use https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/getting-started from nuget

Comment: I already create this Box,but I want to animate it.How to do this?